# How to return a boolean in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been learning Haskell using learnyouahaskell, and I have run into a problem on a program I've been attempting. I want to evaluate three Num inputs representing sides of a triangle, and see if they represent a right triangle. Here is what I have so far:

```
isRight :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool
isRight x y z = (x^2 + y^2) == z^2
```

Obviously the function will need to be longer to allow for different orders of sides, but for now I'm unable to use the function due to this error in GCHI:

```
Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from use of '==' from the context (Num a) 
    bound by the type signature for
        isRight :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
    at isRight.hs:2:1-34
```

Obviously I do not understand how to return a boolean type in Haskell, and I have been unable to find any help pertaining to this problem online. I would be grateful if somebody would help to explain this to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your problem is not with returning Bool. The trouble is that not all members of the `Num` typeclass are also members of the `Eq` typeclass. This will fix your code.

```
isRight :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool
isRight x y z = (x^2 + y^2) == z^2
```

You can read more about typeclasses from the relevant section of the very book you're reading: [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).

Comment: Thank you! So saying `(Num a, Eq a)` is essentially stating that a can be a member of either the `Num` or `Eq` typeclass.

Comment: @lfnunley: It means that `a` is a member of *both* Num and Eq (which it has to be to work with your function). If it's only a member of one, then it doesn't satisfy the type.

Comment: Specifically you need `Num` in order to use `(^)` and `(+)`, and you need `Eq` in order to use `(==)`.